# Не передается объект mysqli в глобальной переменной $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

На странице с которой передается объект mysqli устанавливается соединение с MySQL:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
$_SESSION['link']=$link;
var_dump($link);
```

вывод var_dump:

> object(mysqli)#2 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=>
> string(13) "mysqlnd 7.4.8" ["client_version"]=> int(70408)
> ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0)
> ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { }
> ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(30) "site.tech via
> TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=>
> string(31) "5.7.21-20-log" ["server_version"]=> int(50721)
> ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10)
> ["thread_id"]=> int(40973163) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

На странице приемнике вывод var_dump:

```
$link=$_SESSION['link'];
var_dump($link);
```

> object(mysqli)#1 (3) { ["client_version"]=> int(70408)
> ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL }

На каждой странице выполняется session_start();

Почему объект mysqli передается не весь?

Comment: А зачем это делать?

Comment: Потому что соединение с БД нельзя запихнуть в сессию. Как и открытый файл.

Comment: @u_mulder ну это-то понятно. Битва за производительность. Ведь соединение с БД - это настолько тяжелая операция, что если делать её на каждой странице, то сайт начнет падать уже при посещаемости 10 человек в сутки.

Comment: @Ипатьев т.е. надо на каждой странице снова соединяться с БД? Или есть варианты?

Comment: Нет, вариантов нету. Писать код каждый раз конечно, не стоит, для этого есть `require`. Но соединяться надо каждый раз заново. Вот хорошее руководство про то, что должно быть в таком файле: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect

Comment: @Ипатьев спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Вероятно требуется постоянное соединение:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("p:" . $host, $user, $password, $db_name);
```

Префикс `p:` к имени хоста. Об этом написано, например на [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-pconnect.php)

> Альтернативы для данной функции: > mysqli_connect() с p: префиксом хоста

**upd** - такое соединение **вместо** использования сессии

Comment: Вероятно надо внимательно читать вопрос, перед тем как бежать строчить ответ

Comment: если отвечать на вопрос "почему", то ответ 
 есть здесь - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.session.php

`Внимание Так как сессионные данные сериализуются, то переменные с типом resource не могут храниться в сессиях. `

в своем ответе же указал способ, который приводит к меньшему количеству отдельных соединений с БД (если это было целью добавления соединения в сессию)

Comment: + нашел, на такой же вопрос был такой же ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125403/cant-pass-mysqli-connection-in-session-in-php

Comment: как же тяжело с людьми, которые пытаются давать советы в области, в которой не имеют ни малейшего практического опыта,  а только нахватались по верхам разных умных слов. использование постоянных соединений приводит не к уменьшению, а к **увеличению** отдельных соединений. Вместо того чтобы соединиться, выполнить работу, и разъединиться, РНР теперь держит большое количество **постоянно открытых одновременных соединений** с БД.